# multiple items on different rows of pandas dataframe to coulmns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

Here is the text of the same image (for convenience):

```
                   ticker     field       value
0  NESNVX 0 06/14/26 Corp   px_last      95.083
1  NESNVX 0 06/14/26 Corp    coupon           0
2  NESNVX 0 06/14/26 Corp  maturity  2026-06-14
3       BE0002256254 Corp   px_last      98.201
4       BE0002256254 Corp    coupon           1
5       BE0002256254 Corp  maturity  2026-07-22
6       BE0002276450 corp   px_last      98.423
7       BE0002276450 corp    coupon       1.375
8       BE0002276450 corp  maturity  2027-04-07
```

The ticker column is repeated by n fields. So, for example, if there are 3 unique `field` items, the `ticker` is repeated 3 times (as in the example above).

How do i transform this to a grid such that it is just `tickers` (as index) vs `fields` (as the column headers) with the `value` as the elements of the matrix ?

I have tried to use the `groupby` function, but cannot seem to get this to work the way i need it to.

The result that i seek, would be this:

```
    ticker                    px_last   coupon    maturity
0   NESNVX 0 06/14/26 Corp    95.083    0         2026-06-14
1   BE0002256254 Corp         98.201    1         2026-07-22
2   BE0002276450 corp         98.423    1.375     2027-04-07
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pandas.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot) might be what you are looking for.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ticker': [
        'NESNVX 0 06/14/26 Corp',
        'NESNVX 0 06/14/26 Corp',
        'NESNVX 0 06/14/26 Corp',
        'BE0002256254 Corp',
        'BE0002256254 Corp',
        'BE0002256254 Corp',
        'BE0002276450 corp',
        'BE0002276450 corp',
        'BE0002276450 corp'
    ],
    'field': ['px_last', 'coupon', 'maturity', 'px_last', 'coupon', 'maturity', 'px_last', 'coupon', 'maturity'],
    'value': [95.083, 0, '2026-06-14', 98.201, 1, '2026-07-22', 98.423, 1.375, '2027-04-07']
})

result = df.pivot(index='ticker', columns='field', values='value')
```

This creates dataframe with `field` column as index, to use integer index and set `field` as a column, you can use:

```py
result.reset_index(inplace=True)
result = result.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
            ticker  coupon  maturity    px_last
0   BE0002256254 Corp   1   2026-07-22  98.201
1   BE0002276450 corp   1.375   2027-04-07  98.423
2   NESNVX 0 06/14/26 Corp  0   2026-06-14  95.083
```

Comment: This is nearly ideal.  the only part that is odd is that field is now the index, whereas the index is usually blank in a pandas df.  great answer so far !

Comment: Yes, that is what I point out in the second half of my answer :)

Comment: I slightly modded the answer with this `result = result.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)`.  Which gives the exact desired output. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

one of the way is to create another dictionary to fit what you need in this case :
suppose that df is your initial database

```
Dict=dict()
Dict['ticker']=[]
for n in range(len(df)//3):
    Dict['ticker'].append(df.loc[3*n][0])
    Dict[df.loc[n][1]]=[]
    
for n in range(len(df)):
    Dict[df.loc[n%3][1]].append(df.loc[n][2])

df2=pd.DataFrame(Dict)
```

Comment: this might work and looks good, but it is more optimal using @druskacik answer as it is one line and vectorized compared to loops.  But nevertheless, a clever answer.